# Trust wallet /wallet connect send transaction with thorchain/bsc/binance or someothe chain

Tags: walletconnect, trustwallet

I have a working example how to allow user to transfer eth, how to let him transfer bsc, or thorchain or someother network?

**This is how I Connect wallet**

```
import WalletConnect from "@walletconnect/client";
import QRCodeModal from "@walletconnect/qrcode-modal";    
const connector = new WalletConnect({
        bridge: "https://bridge.walletconnect.org", // Required
        qrcodeModal: QRCodeModal,
      });    
 document.onreadystatechange = () => {
            // Create a connector          
      // Check if connection is already established
      if (!connector.connected) {
        // create new session
        connector.createSession();
      }
}
```

**THis is how I can transfer eth tokens:**

```
const tx2 = {

  from: "0xbc28Ea04101F03aA7a94C1379bc3AB32E65e62d3", // Required
  to: "0x89D24A7b4cCB1b6fAA2625Fe562bDd9A23260359", // Required (for non contract deployments)
  data: "0x", // Required
  // gasPrice: "0x02540be400", // Optional
  // gas: "0x9c40", // Optional
  // value: "0x00", // Optional
  // nonce: "0x0114", // Optional
};

// Send transaction
self.connector
  .sendTransaction(tx2)
  .then((result) => {
    // Returns transaction id (hash)
    console.log(result);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    // Error returned when rejected
    console.error(error);
  });
```

**This is the code works ONLY for eth transactions**

**How to specify other chain ?** (for example thorchain or binance smart chain or btc chain )?

I've tried to use `trust_signTransaction` but this didn't help, details here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69493167/trust-wallet-dapp-connect-and-sign-transfer-message

Answer (score 0):

> How to specify other chain ?

There is no API for wallets to specify another chain. The only way for this to happen is that you detect the chain by `chainId` and then ask the user to switch the chain.

You can get the `chainId` with [web3.eth.getChainId() method](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.5.2/web3-eth.html#getchainid). The list of [supported chain ids can be found in Chainlist](https://chainlist.org/).

Comment: you didn't get my question bro) I need a sample of code to transfer for example on chain bsc (if bsc is connected) you answered some other question I didn't ask